# Will there be antisemitism in 35th century?

Tags: futurology, far-future

Will there still be antisemitism in 35th century?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and really there will be no one right answer. Some may picture a world without humans, without racism, without religions, without regular human-human contact...in so long a time anything could happen. Perhaps if you narrowed your question down by defining what you think would have happened in the interim this might help. Also is there a particular reason you choose anti-Semitism for your story rather than racism against another religion?

Comment: If you as a worldbuilder wishes there to be, there will be, in the world you are building. If you do not wish it, there will not be. As far as real life goes... no-one can tell.

Comment: Along the same lines, one might first as "Will there still be Judaism in the 35th century?"  The answers to that question and their reasons may give a great deal of information which can be used to start answering your question.

Comment: @LioElbammalf: a word without Jews, or without any other race than Jews...

Comment: Actually - nope. There are two likely options. Option 1) There is nobody left, antisemitism extinct with the human race, Option 2) we're through AI singularity, so everyone's robots or virtual, no more races.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a better question would be, will there be Jews as a distinct people in the 35th century?

Since they have been around for ~4000 years so far, I would say likely they would still be around in another 1500 years.

Any group is likely to have some people who don't like them, so I would say **Yes** anti Semitism is likely to still be around, but whether or not it is widespread or socially acceptable is impossible to know.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate that Judaism has, in the past, survived well you cannot extrapolate that survival to the next 1500 years. Atheism was rare until recently - we could just as easily say **"Well in the past 50 years the number of atheists has jumped up from practically 0 to ~50% in places...I would say in the next 100 years there will be no religion at all."** I don't support that but I'm just pointing out the pressure to follow any religion Is changing. We can't say what will happen in the next 1500 years based on the past.

Comment: @LioElbammalf I would agree that predicting 1500 years in the future is going to be very speculative for anything, but Judaism over 4000 years has had many large coordinated attempts to wipe them out and they are still around as a group, that is the mark of a survivor.  As far as atheism goes I think a number of people who identify themselves as Jews could also consider themselves atheists, the grouping is often more cultural than strictly religious.

Comment: @Lio Elbammalf religious antisemitism is olnly one variety, there can be antisemitism is a full-atheist world.

Answer (score 0):

Antisematism is at least 4000 years old.  Its prevalence waxes and wanes but remains. It seems unlikely to me that if humans remain humans that it would ever go away entirely. Humans don't need much excuse to hate any group of "others", and a group claiming to be God's chosen people can particularly stir emotions in the unchosen population.

There are very few things that have endured with humanity for so long. I would give this a high chance of continuing to exist, unless by then there are no more Jews or all of humanity has converted to Judism... but then we'd probably find some other schism to divide us.

Comment: That the Babylonians or the Assirians or the Romans did wage wars agains the Hebrews is not actually "Antisematism[sic]"; it was just as the world was in these days (and it is not as if the Hebrews of the day did anyting different when they could). The only difference with lots of other peoples is that Hebrews did survive through all of that.

Comment: Shall we go with 2800 years then after the diaspora of Israel as a nation? @SJuan76

Comment: Certainly we should not even consider any time before the split between early Christianism and Judaism (70 A.D), and it would have been irrelevant until Christianism became an important force in the Roman Empire (4th century)

Comment: @SJuan76 You and I will have to disagree on this point. I would lump the subjugation in Egypt under this heading.

Comment: I acknowledge that there is a current that wants to emphasize Jewish suffering through history (often as a means of excusing the actuation of the current Israeli government against other peoples) but this account makes no sense. Not only historicity of the "Egyptian captivity" has been severely questioned, but imperialist politics do not denote prosecution (in the same manner that there was nothing "anti-indian" in the British Raj, other than the British could profit from India). This is in the same level of absurdity of calling the Roman Empire "anti-Celtic", "anti-Egyptian" or "anti-Greek".

Comment: You could as well say that there is a constant "anti-Greekism", "anti-Syrianism" or "anti-Persianism", since from the Classic Age people from all around the world have attacked, invaded, and conquered the territories of Greece, Syria and Persia. That is how the world has worked since the dawn of times, and pretending that the Jewish case is an exceptional one is denying history or falsifying it. The mixup of a (legendary) occupation by a foreign power with actual targetted antisemitism is quite farfetched.

Comment: I agree with anti-Greekism, anti-Syrianism, etc. Every war I have ever studied or lived through has been country A at war with country B, and then the citizens of A start hating the individual citizens of B who happen to be in A when the war starts. And it usually lasts beyond the war. In that regard, the Jews are nothing special. The only thing that seems to distinguish anti-Semitism is that so many cultures have practiced it and it keeps coming back up. I have my suspicion that it is the phrase "God's chosen people" that triggers the backlash, but I have no data to back that theory. @SJuan76